# Optimising Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I'm working with Apache in my .htaccess doc, but I'm still very much of a beginner and wondered if anyone here could help me.

Basically, I'm creating a website with a help page.
*`www.website.com/help`* is the help page home, and *`www.website.com/help/contact`* is one of its sub pages. Obviously there's be more then just "contact".

This is what I've written so far:

```
RewriteRule    ^help$                    help.php            [NC]
RewriteRule    ^help/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)     help.php?dsp=$1     [NC]
```

Is there a way to compact that into one line? Or any advice to improve it in anyway if possible?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't mind getting a `dsp` parameter that is blank, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^help(?:/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)|)$ help.php?dsp=$1 [NC]
```

The `(?:)` is a conditional capture group. So it is either `/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` or nothing at all. Thus the backreference `$1` is either `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` or nothing at all (giving you a blank `dsp` parameter).